# Finding the collection details if one field is distinct

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I have a database of teachers details as given

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bcc0a44f2752576a8545d99"), "Teacher_id" : "Pic002", "Teacher_Name" : "Ravi Kumar", "Dept_Name" : "IT", "Salary" : 40000, "Status" : "A" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bcc0a5af2752576a8545d9a"), "Teacher_id" : "Pic003", "Teacher_Name" : "Akshay", "Dept_Name" : "Comp", "Salary" : 25500, "Status" : "N" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bcc0a85f2752576a8545d9b"), "Teacher_id" : "Pic003", "Teacher_Name" : "Akshay", "Dept_Name" : "Comp", "Salary" : 25500, "Status" : "N" }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bcc0a9af2752576a8545d9c"), "Teacher_id" : "Pic004", "Teacher_Name" : "Sumit", "Dept_Name" : "Mech", "Salary" : 35000, "Status" : "N" }
```

How would I list down complete details of a teacher whose Department Name is distinct?

Basically, I want to display the details of the first first and last document in this collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this via this aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: "$Dept_Name",
      docs: {
        $addToSet: "$$CURRENT"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "count": {
        "$eq": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$docs"
    }
  }
])
```

The idea is first to [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) and at the same time keep the objects via [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html).
Then filter (via [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html)) on those which count is 1 and then $unwind & [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html).

See it working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eA7LxYcXLGK)